# Why .htaccess file is empty'?

Tags: wordpress

When I go to Options->Permalinks and update my permalinks, ".htaccess" did not appear. I tried to put a blank .htaccess file manually. Then go to Options->Permalinks and update again my permalinks. But the .htaccess file is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP process must be able to write your file, so you have to [check the file permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#.htaccess_permissions). You can do this using your FTP tool or on the command line (`chmod` command), if you are on UNIX.

File permission for `.htaccess` files is usually set to `644`.

Comment: Check the file permission. Are you on linux or windows system?

Comment: godaddy linux server. I set it 644, but this does not help.

Comment: Can you check ``phpinfo()`` and see if Safe Mode is enabled? In general, can other PHP scripts write files on your server? It is very likely this is a permission's problem.